# How to find table name using primary key name in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, key

I have names of primary keys in a variable and I need to find the table to which they belong. The db has many table so linear search is not an option.

Comment: Which database  are you using (Oracle , Mysql , Postgres ...) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this out ::

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_Schema.columns 
WHERE column_name='dept_id' 
  and ordinal_position = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `information_schema` tables.  If the primary key name is the first column in the table, you can just do:

```
select table_name
from information_schema.columns
where column_name in (<your list here>) and
      ordinal_position = 1;
```

Otherwise, you have to go through the constraints to get what you want.  Something like:

```
select kcu.table_name, kcu.column_name
from information_schema.table_constraints tc join
     information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
     on tc.contraint_name = kcu.contraint_name and
        tc.table_name = kcu.table_name
where tc.contraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY' and
      column_name in (<your list here>);
```

You can also do this using the system tables and views.

Comment: first query seems to have a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, please try it:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(constraint_name), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
AND column_name in (select column_name from <your list here>)
```

Below solution wouldn't work if the primary key constraint is set to any column other than that of the first column in `CREATE TABLE' query.

```
select table_name
from information_schema.columns
where column_name in (select column_name from <your list here>) and
ordinal_position = 1
```

For example, it wouldn't work if we create table like this:

```
create table sample1
(
 field1 int,
 field2 int primary key
)
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The below query gives tablename based on constraint name

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
where CONSTRAINT_NAME ='<ConstraintName>'
```

Answer (score 0):

To find table name using primary key name follow this below query

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where
CONSTRAINT_NAME =<ConstraintName>

---Find the below views to get constraint details in a db select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS select * from
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS select * from
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE
```

Answer (score 0):

improved from above answer

```
 select kcu.table_name, kcu.column_name, *
    from information_schema.table_constraints tc join
    information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
    on tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME and
    tc.table_name = kcu.table_name
    where tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'PK__DC_INPUT__7EA5540496A9FD5D'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [TABLE_NAME]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'YourPrimaryKey';
```